# UserDefaults - NSMutibleArray Loop

Tags: objective-c

The Mutible array contains doubles

It takes the currently saved `array` adds new `doubles` then re-saves it.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaultDefects = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *loadDefects = [defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultDefects"];

[loadDefects addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.defectPositionX ]];
[loadDefects addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.defectPositionY ]];

[defaultDefects setObject:loadDefects forKey:@"defaultDefects"];
```

Then to load them I require this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaultDefects = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *loadDefects = [defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultDefects"];

//in here I need a foreach loop so it would be something like

double defectX = 0;
double defectY = 0;
int keyValue;    

foreach (loadDefects as key => value) {
    double defectX = [[loadDefects objectAtIndex:keyValue] doubleValue];
    keyValue++;
    double defectY = [[loadDefects objectAtIndex:keyValue] doubleValue];
    keyValue++;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, defectX, defectY);
}
```

I've wrote this to make sense programatically, not the correct way of writing it in Objective-C as that is what I'm trying to figure out.. Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: I think he's asking how to use a foreach loop

Comment: ^^ That's exactly what I'm asking, but I need to use two keys inside the loop, for example.. key [0] = defectX; key [1] = defectY; then next loop key[2] = defectX; key[3] = defectY; and so on for however many saved defects there are in the array.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop in your pseudo code makes no sense: you are extracting keys and values from an `NSMutableArray`. An array does not associate values with keys. Also, depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to store your data as `CGPoint` encapsulated in `NSValue`s instead of doubles in `NSNumber`.

Comment: An array does not associate values with keys? But it does associate keys with values..? I'll look into CGPoint

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis I've edited my pseudo so it makes more sense of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @DanielWatson No, an array does not associate key with values, you're looking for a hashmap or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you need make `for` cycle with step "2" for retrieving `X` and `Y` in one cycle step. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loadDefects.count; i += 2) {
    double defectX = [loadDefects[i] doubleValue];
    double defectY = [loadDefects[i+1] doubleValue];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, defectX, defectY);
}
```

Also don't forget initialize `loadDefects` array at first app launch and save changes in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSMutableArray *loadDefects = [defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultDefects"];
if (loadDefects == nil) {
    loadDefects = [NSMutableArray array];
}
// ...
// Add elements to array and store it defaultDefects here
// ...
[defaultDefects synchronize];
```

Comment: I added an NSLog into the for loop and it returns nothing (doesn't return at all), which would make me assume that the doubles aren't being added to the array. Is there an error on my adding them to the mutable array part?

Comment: Are you sure that this line returns non-empty array: `NSMutableArray *loadDefects = [defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultDefects"];`

Comment: yeah that is what I'm assuming, as it doesn't enter the for loop at all. But my method to saving the array is in the first part of the code, can you see any issues with it?

Comment: Top guy, it works a charm now. The only issue is that it runs the loop twice, but it's drawing over the same lines so it's not really an issue. Thanks a bunch!